# Is it possible to completely hide the admin menu for a role, while still grant it some admin permissions?

Tags: 8, users

I need to create a 'Demo' role that can completely hide the admin menu toolbar, but can still access some admin pages to, well, demonstrate stuff.

What would be the best way to do this in drupal 8? Is there some kind of built in functionality to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck "Use the administration toolbar" for the 'demo' role under Users > Permissions.